# php script longer than max execution time (progress bar)

Tags: php, mysql, execution-time

i currently work on a small project, where some data is gathered from the web and the system creates some relations between these. Of course it was not perfect from the beginning, so i needed to make a script which updates all the connections and relations with the updated scripts i made.

Basically the script works, but as there shall be a nice looking backend afterwards, its not really what i want.

The script needs around 10 minutes and because i didnt just want to set up the max_execution_time from php i thought of another method. Instead of loading 1000 sql entries at once i stripped it down to 200 at one time and just repeat it with the next 200 when the first round finished. Therefore i used php http_request. I just show you a stripped down version of the script:

```
require_once 'HTTP/Request.php'; 
$max = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) as max FROM db_table");
$lower = $_POST['lower'] ? $_POST['lower'] : 0;
$plus = 250;
$entries = $db->query("SELECT * FROM db_table LIMIT {$lower},{$plus}");

foreach($entries as $entry){
  DO SOME STUFF TO UPDATE THE RELATIONS BETWEEN THE DATA
}

$lower = $lower + $plus;

if($lower <= $max) {
  $request = new HTTP_Request("path to the script"); 
  $request->setMethod(HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_POST); 
  $request->addPostData("lower", $lower);
  $result = $request->sendRequest(); 
}
```

This is it. As i said it works, because it's a new request so that it's not affected by the max_execution_time. But the browser is just loading and loading and loading and after a while it finishes. But of course i cannot show any refreshed data for something like a progress bar.

I saw many entries using php flush(), but that didnt work for me because of the (i guess) stupid way i used to solve my problem. 
How would you do this if you need to install something on a webspace and you dont have the possbility to change the max execution time or install http_request?

As i said it should look like a progress bar later on. I guess i have to use ajax, and simply push the round the script is at every round and update the progress bar via javascript.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are still having trouble with max_execution_time because the page you requested from web browser is always active one, it doesn't finish until the HTTPRequests finishes. Try locating the page to another with the parameter lower.

```
header("Location: myscript.php?lower=$lower");
```

Comment: No i have no trouble with the execution time. The execution time is set to 30 secs and the script takes around 12 minutes. 
If i just used header - would the ajax script notice that?

Comment: Are you calling this from an ajax post/get command? you haven't mentioned that in your question.

Comment: If you are using ajax, you should handle this iteration using javascript. When a page loaded successfully go to another with the parameter lower. So you can update the progress bar after every successful request.

Comment: Not using ajax so far, i just mentioned that i think, that ill call the script via ajax later on - iteration via javascript is not the best way in my opinion. Best thing would be if the Script would work all alone ;) 
How does other software do this, when you have a big installer with different steps?